# Difference between PowerBuilder v8 and PowerBuilder v12

Tags: powerbuilder

What is the difference between [PowerBuilder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBuilder) 8 and PowerBuilder 12?

Comment: 4 cylinders. <-- joke

Answer (score 8):

Yikes. Well, first off, six major versions. (Sybase has been on an x.5 binge since v10.) I'm hoping you don't think six versions can be described in one page, although Stephanie did a pretty good job with one line. <*grin*>

Since I don't know what rocks your boat (web services may make one happy, while another has been looking for new menu styles for years, while yet another might get ecstatic that the new overload of Trim() will improve the performance of his nightly batch process enough that he can go to bed on time), let me refer you to [my list of PowerBuilder history](http://www.techno-kitten.com/Changes_to_PowerBuilder/changes_to_powerbuilder.html), which will get you from v8 to v11.5. (Yes, v12 is missing: long story, no one cares. It'll get fixed.) Hopefully by browsing through there, you'll find what is useful for you and your specific application.

If you're looking to move your application to something that can compete with the best GUIs out there, v12 is a game changer. PB.NET gives you not only access to WPF, which has some pretty strong potential in the GUI building department, but also gives you access to the .NET framework. Getting into it is a relatively painless migration process (more difficult than most PB migrations, less difficult than a rewrite <*grin*>), which will get you into the waters and let you start experimenting with how to take advantage of all that potential. If you're not ready for that kind of leap yet (the migration is one-way), there's still PB Classic for Win32, WinForms and WebForms development. You get both environments when you get v12.

Good luck,

Terry

Answer (score 5):

I am sure there are many little differences, but from a high-level, it's still pretty much the same.
I use PB12 classic ( not .NET ), and it's pretty much the same thing that it was back in PB7.  It still sucks pretty badly compared to more modern languages and IDEs.  It still crashes the IDE quite often.  The powerscript language is the same, and is now way behind more modern languages like Python, C#, Ruby, etc.  It even seems old compared to Java!  You still get strange behaviors if you don't manually regenerate objects in the right order.  The debugger still refuses to remove breakpoints, and will crash often.  So, in my experience, PB12 is not hugely different from previous versions.

So, if you have an existing app, then go ahead and upgrade -- there are probably tons of bug fixes and stuff.
If you have PB8 and want to start a new app then get started in PB8 and see how it goes -- you can upgrade later.
If you are considering starting a brand new app in PowerBuilder, then...consider alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

A major change is that string and char variables are Unicode (2 bytes) instead of Ansi (1 byte).